# Specifics of orbiting self-interaction in GR?

Tags: general-relativity, orbital-motion, geodesics, gravitational-lensing, interactions

As the orbiting body emits its own gravitational field, its front would curve around the host. In doing so, if the lensing caused by the host is sufficient, it could hypothetically intersect with the body at a later point in that body's orbit.

[image: Orbiting body]

I recognize that the geodesic length of the light-like gravitational front traveling past the host must equal the geodesic length of the time-like orbiting body. Otherwise, they won't meet. I just don't know if that's actually possible. That is to say: **is there an orbit wherein these two geodesic lengths can be equal, bringing them together at the same point in spacetime?**

It seems to me that the mass and angular momentum of the host and orbiting body, perihelion distance, and eccentricity of the orbit would all have to be finely-tuned together for this to happen.

If necessary, feel free to assume that $m<<M$, but I'd honestly prefer a consideration for the general case.

Comment: I don't think that the geodesic lengths should be equal is the right criterion, rather the geodesic deviation vector b/w two trajectories should vanish after some finite time. The question is if such a solution for deviation vector (b/w timelike trajectory of m and null trajectory of GW) can exist or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We interact with the electromagnetic radiation emitted by ourselves every time we look in the mirror. So to answer this question we need a gravitational analog of a mirror. One well known spacetime that has mirror properties is the Scwarzschild metric. Recall, that it has a photon sphere, where a photon can stay in an *unstable* circular orbit indefinitely. But this means that we can use this photon sphere orbit as a “storage ring” for photons (or gravitons), and by adjusting initial parameters by tiniest amounts we can put a photon in a nearly circular orbit, where it would circle the central body (black hole) a desired number of turns and then exit the orbit in a prescribed direction chosen to intersect the emitter trajectory.

> [I]s there an orbit wherein these two geodesic lengths can be equal, bringing them together at the same point in spacetime?

As long as there is a photon sphere around the body $M$, the orbit of $m$ could be practically anything and there would be null geodesics originating and terminating on $m$'s worldline. In fact there would be an infinite sequence of such geodesics parametrized by a number of turns in the photon sphere (in either direction), for any moment of emission from $m$ (infinite, assuming that bodies remain eternally visible and not, say, collide or disappear behind each others cosmic horizons). There are no particular restrictions on masses of either body as long as the photon sphere of $M$ retains its properties.

A few papers that discuss this “mirror” property:

- Stuckey, W. M. (1993). *The Schwarzschild black hole as a gravitational mirror*. American journal of physics, 61(5), 448-456, [doi:10.1119/1.17434](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.17434), [free pdf](http://cosmo.fis.fc.ul.pt/%7Ecrawford/papers/Stuckey.pdf).
- Nemiroff, Robert J. "Visual distortions near a neutron star and black hole." American Journal of Physics 61.7 (1993): 619-632, [doi:10.1119/1.17224](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.17224), [arXiv:astro-ph/9312003](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9312003).
- Cramer, C. R. (1997). Using the uncharged Kerr black hole as a gravitational mirror. General Relativity and Gravitation, 29(4), 445-454, [doi:10.1023/A:1018878515046](https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1018878515046).

Comment: Allow me to reiterate to verify that I'm following you correctly. The front of the gravitational influence of m can be captured by the photon sphere and at some arbitrary time later find its way out of orbit due to the photon sphere being a state of unstable equilibrium. In escaping, this gravitational front may then be coincident with m at a future time. Is that right?

Comment: I was already familiar with the photon sphere. I suppose I just never thought about outwards release. For some reason, inward release was all that ever occured to me.

Comment: @LoganJ.Fisher: *Is that right?* Right. Instead of  “front of gravitational influence” we can also talk about propagation of perturbations of gravitational field or propagation of gravitons, these are the different terms for same(ish) concept.

Comment: Does the gravitational front leave with any difference in strength than it entered with?

Comment: @LoganJ.Fisher *unstable orbit* means that a wavepacket propagating along it would be constantly diffusing and losing amplitude, and with multiple turns the “strength” would be exponentially reduced.

Comment: … If you are interested in spacetimes that behave more like *focusing mirrors* that could could gather front strength into one specific point, consider anti-de Sitter spacetime. In fact small gravitational perturbation in such background can be focused to the point of forming a black hole.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the wavelength of "gravitons" generated by a binary are typically larger than the photonsphere. Consequently, geometric optics isn't a very good approximation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific orbital requirements for this to happen, although being in the strong field regime helps tremendously. When an object travels through a curved spacetime some of its "gravitational interaction" will refract off the curvature back onto its own trajectory, causing the object to interact with its own gravitational field. The resulting interaction is known as the gravitational self-force.* In the limit, $m<<M$ this can be used to model the dynamics of relativistic binaries (e.g. see [this review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.10385)).

However, this also happens in the comparable mass regime. For example, so called "tail terms" in the post-Newtonian approximation arise as integrals over terms scattered off the common gravitational potential.

It is also possible for an object directly interact with its own gravitational radiation when it intersects its own lightcone. Such points are also known as caustics and as A.V.S. explained in his answer are generally present for black hole binaries due to the existences of photonspheres around the black holes. One thing to note is that gravitational waves generated by a binary always have a longer wavelength than the size of the photonorbits. Consequently, the geometric optics assumption used to justify that answer does not strictly apply. What happens instead is that the quasi-normal modes of the black holes get excited, and the other black holes feel the effects of these QNMs. This particular effect was studied in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.06791).

*) Note same thing happens for electromagnetic (or other) interactions in a curved spacetime leading to an electromagnetic self-force.